# Any simple way to add PuTTY settings to kitty?

Tags: putty, kitty

I'd like to use Kitty, but I have a lot of settings for Putty already set up.  I read that there is no way to "export settings" with Putty since they are made with registry entries, and there is probably no way to "import" these settings into Kitty either.  Does anyone know of a utility that allows you to do this somehow?

Comment: I've installed KiTTy and all my settings from PuTTy are in there. Maybe it is a version mismatch?

Comment: Do you happen to be using a portable version of either that didn't install their settings to the registry?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To copy PuTTY reg to KiTTY reg, start any KiTTY session, then press CTRL+F8 and enter

```
/copytokitty
```

To copy KiTTY settings from registry mode, to portable mode use the command-line and run

```
kitty.exe -convert-dir
```

Cyd

Comment: That's an awesome hint.

Comment: This description seems unclear to me. At least I did not get it working. Can you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: Ctrl+F8 has no effect for me. What it is supposed to do?

Comment: **Security note**: IMO, Portable is more **secure** approach I think. So, after you convert to portable, then delete registry values (save  backup of that registry at first if you want).

Answer (score 9):

Cyd's answer seems to apply to Kitty Classic (not Portable).

I have been unable to get PuTTY settings directly into KittyPortable.  The problem is that, being portable, KittyPortable does not even LOOK at the C drive, so it can't read the PuTTY keys in the Windows registry.

I was able to accomplish it indirectly by installing Kitty Classic, which automagically picked up PuTTY's registry keys, and then running

`KittyPortable.exe -convert-dir`

==========================================================================

## If you do NOT have administrative rights on your PC, continue reading. Otherwise, skip down.

This approach will not work if you don't have sufficient privileges to install Kitty Classic.  Many people do not have admin rights on their PC at work, but this is where you might want to use KittyPortable.

So you need to convert your PuTTY settings to Kitty on a machine you have admin rights on, such as your home machine.  But maybe your home machine doesn't have the PuTTY config settings that you use at work.

So you would need to export your PuTTY registry keys at work and import them on your home PC.

Run regedit, select

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions`

and do File/Export (make sure the radio button for "selected branch" is selected).  Then go to a PC on which you have admin rights (your home PC, maybe), install PuTTY, double-click the exported registry file that you exported earlier (this imports all the PuTTY sessions), and then...

=========================================================================

## resuming...

- Create a folder somewhere called kitty_portable (preferably not on
  the C drive).
- Download both the Windows Classic and Windows Portable
  versions of Kitty from http://www.downloadbestsoft.com/KiTTY.html and
  put them in your kitty_portable folder.
- Launch kitty.exe.  It will pull in all of your PuTTY config settings.  Close kitty.exe.
- Go to a DOS shell, cd to the kitty_portable directory, and type: 

  `KittyPortable.exe -convert-dir`
- Delete kitty.exe (you won't ever need it again)

Running KittyPortable.exe with the -convert-dir param will create several folders in your kitty_portable folder, including all of your PuTTY settings (which are now stored in plain textfiles instead of using the registry, like PuTTY does. This folder is 100% portable and does not even access the C drive.

Whew.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit all the session passwords in bulk? I tried manually via notepad++ but it doesn't work out because those passwords need to be encrypted.

Comment: Now, kitty portable does that too as i see.

Comment: amazing thanks so much

Comment: I'll leave something here that may help someone in future: If you're trying to import the registry settings using classic, make sure you don't have kitty.ini, Proxies and Sessions folders in your working directory (if you previously ran portable version), otherwise classic won't import your settings; delete them and try again.

Answer (score 2):

2021 test on Windows 10 and 11

export reg from

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\
```

Import to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\9bis.com\KiTTY\Sessions\
```

Comment: For future users, this is the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can export Putty's registry settings using the Windows registry editor. This produces a text file which you can edit with your favourite text editor (Notpad, Notepad++, gVim, etc).

As Kitty is a fork of Putty, I expect that Kitty's settings are in an almost identical structure but perhaps just need one part of the registry path changing. You can probably find this quite easily using the registry editor.

After editing the text file to suit Kitty, importing the registry file (normally a matter of double-clicking the .reg filename in Windows explorer) ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that some versions of kitty don't show sessions stored in registry if kitty.exe is copied to putty's program foder.